# How to use apache2 to listen to the url name and redirect the signal to the appropriate server

Tags: apache-2.2

I was wondering how I can use Apache2 to listen for the URL of the website that the user is trying to access to then redirect it to another server on the local network running on a different port?

For example I have the following websites:

1. dl.MyWebsite.org
2. Other_site.com
3. Business_web_page.xyz
4. web_email_server.net
5. Private_Storage.hi
6. ftp.othersite.com

and lets say that I want to have one server listen on port 80 and find out if the user is trying to acess the `web_email_server.net`website that is running on port `25577` but when the user trys to acess the site on port `80` it will then connect to the server running on port `25577` then return it to port `80`

[image: http://s29.postimg.org/dtue0qypj/Screen_Shot_2014_12_22_at_11_29_51_PM.png]

Comment: My apologizes I must have used the wrong link [New image](http://s29.postimg.org/dtue0qypj/Screen_Shot_2014_12_22_at_11_29_51_PM.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html), but your setup sounds like a poor idea. Just run virtual hosts on the same standard port 80.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with virtual hosts

Comment: [You got some fun reading ahead of you.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/)